# Why are WKNavigationDelegate methods not called on some websites?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, wkwebview

So i want to update some properties like the `UITextField` that holds the `URL` in my application but `WKNavigationDelegate` methods are not being called some website like youtube when I press on a specific video for example.

I have tried adding a `Timer` that updates the `UITextFiled` every 5 seconds which worked but it's not instant and not efficient is there any other way ?

Comment: did you ever resolve this issue?